# Can't get an svg to animate

Tags: svg, raphael

I imported an SVG from InkScape using the ReadySetRaphael tool. I wanted to animate the svg, and ease it in. So just for test purposes, i tried to transform it using the animate method.

I keep getting an error to say my object doesnt have a method of "animate". I've checked other SO answers which suggest i have to clone the object and set the final path, but not sure if that does, or how it applies to me?

Here's my js code so far.

```js
//code created using readysetraphael. Original svg made in inkscape.
var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '744.09448', '1052.3622');

var layer1 = rsr.set();
var path2993 = rsr.path("m 344.93716,348.36218 c 0,0 34.17415,-33.06016 -1.26571,-83.92195 -35.43985,-50.86178 39.23699,-38.14634 6.32855,-91.55121 -32.90844,-53.40487 -50.62837,-36.8748 -50.62837,-36.8748 -9.49282,-0.63577 -8.85996,-0.63577 -8.85996,-0.63577");
path2993.attr({
    id: 'path2993',
    parent: 'layer1',
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: '#cf0000',
    "stroke-width": '2.92',
    "stroke-linecap": 'butt',
    "stroke-linejoin": 'miter',
    "stroke-miterlimit": '4',
    "stroke-opacity": '1',
    "stroke-dasharray": 'none',
    "marker-start": 'none',
    "marker-mid": 'none',
    "marker-end": 'url(#TriangleInL)'
}).data('id', 'path2993');
layer1.attr({
    'id': 'layer1',
    'name': 'layer1'
});

var rsrGroups = [layer1];

//Animate svg
rsr.animate({
    transform: 's2'
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code pulls an animation call over the paper object. As [`animate()` is a member of `Element`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate), the call fails.

I assume you're trying to animate a specific shape, e.g. `path2993`. Simply call it on the relevant element instead:

```js
path2993.animate({transform: 's2'}, 2000);
```

Comment: I actually don't have a paper object. Do I need to initialise that first?

just adding the line above, gives me an error

Uncaught TypeError: Object Raphaël‘s set has no method 'animate'

Comment: You actually *do* have a paper object initialized, you did that calling `var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '744.09448', '1052.3622');`, hence, `rsr` is your paper. Just adding that line won't do you any good, you have to remove the call causing the troubles in the first place (`rsr.animate({transform: 's2'}, 2000);`).